# Can't delete branch SourceTree

Tags: git

I am using Github and also SourceTree. I have made a git clone of my project.

Now when I try to delete a branch I made local, I face the following error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false branch -D develop
error: Cannot delete branch 'develop' checked out at 'C:/Users/näZAN/Documents/Protractor'

Completed with errors, see above.
```

Screenshot:
[image]

I am pretty new to working with branches, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot delete a branch that you are currently on.

If you want to delete the `develop` branch, you'll first need to create and switch to another one.

**Note:** This isn't specific to Sourcetree; this is how git works.